# Android market questions

Tags: google-play-store

On google store, do you actually have control over the purchases you make like access to the pc? For example you decide to buy a movie then can you transfer it to the pc? or if you decide to buy book could you hypothetically add the eBook to kindle?.

So over all the biggest question is "Do you have control over the file purchased and downloaded from google market?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the files you **purchase** you have some limited control over; ones you **rent** you do not.

**Music** - You **purchased** (or uploaded your own) music to Google's Servers. You have a license to these media files. They can be downloaded off the Web version of Google Play Music, or with [Google Play Music Manager](http://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1229970).

**Books** - You **purchased** the book, you have a license to these media files as well, some of these files allow you to obtain copies outside of the Google Play Books app, via the web store.`Web Play Store > My Books > A Book I Owned > How To Read` should present alternative methods to download.

**Movies** - You **rented** the movie. Google Play Movies does not (yet) support purchasing of movie media files, as such it is not yours to do with what you wish. You are limited on time to watch it and availability to move it. You are able to watch it on the Web, Tablet or Phone.